# Is the "Immortals Handbook" series official WotC material?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, product-identification, books, wizards-of-the-coast

Is the *Immortals Handbook* series official WotC material?

Regardless of any thoughts on the general quality, as sources seem conflicted on that, my question only relates to how official these books are.

How valid should I consider them? Are they actual WotC material? Are they acknowledged by WotC? Or are they wholly 3rd party?
Also, for what edition are they intended, anyway?

The series I am referring to includes [this book](https://isbnsearch.org/isbn/9781905471614).

Comment: If you need help determining the edition of a D&D book, you can search this site for a question that might help you, or you can [ask one yourself](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) if you can't find one!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A little web searching reveals a [review](https://1d4chan.org/wiki/User:BloodyStupidJohnson) of ***The Immortals Handbook - Epic Bestiary*** which starts:

> The Immortals Handbook - Epic Bestiary is an hilarious independent splatbook for D&D edition 3.x …

The [rpg.net page](https://index.rpg.net/display-entry.phtml?mainid=9888) reveals that this was the first volume published, [followed by](https://index.rpg.net/display-entry.phtml?mainid=9889) ***The Immortals Handbook: Ascension***, both from Eternity Publishing. The Epic Bestiary was later re-published by Mongoose Publishing. There's what appears to be a publisher's web page [here](https://www.immortalshandbook.com/immortalsindex.htm), which shows a complex tale of cancellations and re-scheduling.

So, none of this material is from WotC. You might well do better to get a copy of ***The Primal Order***, WotC's first ever publication, which deals with immortal beings, or even the ***D&D Immortals*** set, published by TSR. Both are available in PDF on DTRPG.

Comment: This matches what I was able to find